# Image' does not contain a definition for 'texture' and no accessible extension method 'texture' accepting a first argument of type 'Image'

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

This error is constantly popping up in Unity after I imported a project.

This is the code :

```cs
public static void CameraFadeSwap(Texture2D texture){
    if(cameraFade){
        cameraFade.GetComponent<Image>().texture=texture; 
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
Assets\Scripts\Utils\iTween.cs(6016,37): error CS1061: 'Image' does not contain a definition for 'texture' and no accessible extension method 'texture' accepting a first argument of type 'Image' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

How can it be fixed?

Comment: Well it doesn't (see [`Image`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Image.html). Unclear what you are trying

Comment: Will you help me to solve this?
Please check the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67969433/image-does-not-contain-definition-for-texture-no-accessible-extension-method

Answer (score 5):

Well it doesn't (see [`Image`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Image.html)).

---

But I think what you are trying is assign a new [`Image.sprite`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Image-sprite.html) instead.

Therefore you'll need to create a new sprite from that texture using [`Sprite.Create`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/Sprite.Create.html)

```c#
public static void CameraFadeSwap(Texture2D texture)
{
    if(cameraFade)
    {
        var newSprite = Sprite.Create(texture, new Rect(0.0f, 0.0f, texture.width, texture.height), Vector2.one * 0.5f);
        cameraFade.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = newSprite;
    }
}
```