# 'Image' does not contain definition for 'texture' no accessible extension method 'texture' accepting a first argument of type 'Image' could be found

Tags: unity-game-engine

This error is constantly popping in Unity after I imported a project.

This is the code :

```
public static GameObject CameraFadeAdd(){
    if(cameraFade){
        return null;
    }else{          
        //establish colorFade object:
        cameraFade = new GameObject("iTween Camera Fade");
        cameraFade.transform.position= new Vector3(.5f,.5f,Defaults.cameraFadeDepth);
        cameraFade.AddComponent<Image>();
        cameraFade.GetComponent<Image>().texture=CameraTexture(Color.black);    // line 6081
        cameraFade.GetComponent<Image>().color = new Color(.5f,.5f,.5f,0);
        return cameraFade;
    }
}
```

Error is:

```
Assets\Scripts\iTween.cs(6081,37): error CS1061: 'Image' does not contain a definition for 'texture' and no accessible extension method 'texture' accepting a first argument of type 'Image' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: Well, no it hasn't .... I guess you mean rather [`Image.sprite`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Image-sprite.html) or rather use a `RawImage` component and [`RawImage.texture`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.RawImage-texture.html)

Comment: Also in general please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now!

Comment: Hello, derHugo 
I need your help. Can you help me with this question?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69132045/assets-script-facebooktop-fb-cs230-36-error-cs0246-the-type-or-namespace-nam

Answer (score 1):

I actually found this because I was messing with the same package today. It's from an old free AI package "Top Down AI" on the Unity asset store.

Solution:
If you're just wanting to get it to run without the compile errors, all you need to do is go through and comment out all of the lines that have to do with the CameraFade. The example game runs fine without it.

If you're still wanting to fix it, then maybe someone else will be able to tell you something with what I've added below. Although, there are much simpler ways to do a camera fade now.

It appears that this was meant to create a camera fade to a color when the player dies. It's several thousand lines long, so I haven't got it all figured out yet.

It first creates a colored texture:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates and returns a full-screen Texture2D for use with CameraFade.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// Texture2D
    /// </returns>
    /// <param name='color'>
    /// Color
    /// </param>
    public static Texture2D CameraTexture(Color color){
        Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(Screen.width,Screen.height,TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);
        Color[] colors = new Color[Screen.width*Screen.height];
        for (int i = 0; i < colors.Length; i++) {
            colors[i]=color;
        }
        texture.SetPixels(colors);
        texture.Apply();
        return(texture);        
    }
```

...lots of other unrelated code in between, then leads up to the function that the other person posted:

```
/// <summary>
/// Changes a camera fade's texture.
/// </summary>
/// <param name='texture'>
/// A <see cref="Texture2D"/>
/// </param>
public static void CameraFadeSwap(Texture2D texture){
    if(cameraFade){
        cameraFade.GetComponent<Image>().texture=texture;
    }
}
```

... I cut some more out here ...

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates a GameObject (if it doesn't exist) at the default depth that can be used to simulate a camera fade.
/// </summary>
/// <param name='texture'>
/// A <see cref="Texture2D"/>
/// </param>
/// <returns>
/// A <see cref="GameObject"/> for a reference to the CameraFade.
/// </returns>
public static GameObject CameraFadeAdd(Texture2D texture){
    if(cameraFade){
        return null;
    }else{          
        //establish colorFade object:
        cameraFade = new GameObject("iTween Camera Fade");
        cameraFade.transform.position= new Vector3(.5f,.5f,Defaults.cameraFadeDepth);
        cameraFade.AddComponent<Image>();
        cameraFade.GetComponent<Image>().texture=texture;
        cameraFade.GetComponent<Image>().color = new Color(.5f,.5f,.5f,0);
        return cameraFade;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Creates a GameObject (if it doesn't exist) at the default depth filled with black that can be used to simulate a camera fade.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>
/// A <see cref="GameObject"/> for a reference to the CameraFade.
/// </returns>
public static GameObject CameraFadeAdd(){
    if(cameraFade){
        return null;
    }else{          
        //establish colorFade object:
        cameraFade = new GameObject("iTween Camera Fade");
        cameraFade.transform.position= new Vector3(.5f,.5f,Defaults.cameraFadeDepth);
        cameraFade.AddComponent<Image>();
        cameraFade.GetComponent<Image>().texture=CameraTexture(Color.black);
        cameraFade.GetComponent<Image>().color = new Color(.5f,.5f,.5f,0);
        return cameraFade;
    }
}
```